# .htaccess mobile redirect not working with all files of my website

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, user-agent, mobile-website

I've inserted code on .htaccess file for mobile redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*[^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*//.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*=.*
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-WAP-PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:PROFILE} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(Alcatel|Asus|Android|BlackBerry|Ericsson|Fly|Huawei|i-mate|iPAQ|iPhone|iPod|LG-|LGE-|MDS_|MOT-|Nokia|Palm|Panasonic|Pantech|Philips|Sagem|Samsung|Sharp|SIE-|Symbian|Vodafone|Voxtel|WebOS|Windows\s+CE|ZTE-|Zune).*$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/vnd.wap.xhtml\+xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/vnd.wap.wml [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://m.%1/ [L]
```

I have a issue:     The .htaccess file works only with index file, it not redirects with other files of my site.
I tried to write www.example.com/file_different_to_index.php in my phone and website is NOT redirecting to m.example.com/file_different_to_index.php

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://m.%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It has not worked, I've changed the last line by `RewriteRule ^(.*) http://m.%1/$1 [L]` and tried in my phone, redirect not working

Answer (score 0):

If you want another option that works, this is the one time I think handling mobile detect and redirecting works well in PHP.  I use it all the time and it detects even down to the OS if you want.

This works much better and you don't have do do all those conditions in htaccess.

https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect#usage

Check my other answer below for examples of how to use it. Its easy and you can have it working in 10 minutes. Just use a condition statement and then use php to redirect with `header location`.

[Mobile Browser Check IF Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17621874/mobile-browser-check-if-statement/17622043#17622043)

Comment: It works, but I use the htaccess for no copy the code in all php files.
.
.
Your answer works, but I don't have 15 reputation to vote up